# New to Access: How do I obtain the standard deviations for grouped data in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, statistics, summary

I have data on hundreds of horse races. I am trying to Clean and prepare the data for Machine Learning analysis, and I need to transform certain Speed Ratings into Standard Deviation Scores around the Means for each individual race or group of scores.

So, each race is a Group of Scores.
My data look somewhat like this:

[image]

And I am trying to get here:

[image]

Is there an easy way to calculate those Stats WITHIN groups,
as opposed to for the entire population of data?

Can they be automatically entered into the three columns to the Right of the SPD figures?

Thanks for any assistance you are able to offer.

Comment: Options: 1) Build an aggregate query that does GROUP BY on Race then join that query to the original data table; 2) build a report using Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calcs in textboxes in Race group header or footer. In either case, AVE and SD calcs can be done with Avg() and StDev() functions. What is the formula for STD?

Answer (score 0):

Following indication a) from the comment that has been posted, the next Query provides the result that you want:

```
SELECT aggregs.Race, Spd, AVE, SD, Spd-AVE AS STD
FROM
   (SELECT Race, Avg(Spd) AS AVE, StdevP(Spd) AS SD
    FROM tblRaces
    GROUP BY Race) AS Aggregs
INNER JOIN
    tblRaces
ON Aggregs.Race = tblRaces.Race
```

I have used the expression "Spd-AVE" to calculate the values of field STD, although you did not indicate which formula you want. Therefore, you should replace "Spd-AVE" by the specific expression that you want.

If you want to get more familiar with aggregation, you may check the Queries F_Select_w_group_by_aggreg, F_Select_w_group_by_aggreg_Syn, F_Select_w_total_aggreg and F_Select_w_total_aggreg_Syn from the database of examples downloadable from [LightningGuide.net](https://LightningGuide.net).

Note that I am using the function StdevP() because I guess you are handling the total population of data. If it is just a sample, you should rather use Stdev().

Comment: I appreciate the code sample.